# What's faster/better to use: the MySQL or PHP md5 function?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, function, md5

I checked the passwords for the users against the DB.

What is faster, the **MySQL** MD5 function

```
... pwd = MD5('.$pwd.')
```

OR the **PHP** MD5 function

```
... pwd = '.md5($pwd).'
```

What is the right way between the two options?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If your application is only calcullating md5 when someone registers on your site, or is logging in, own many calls to md5 will you do per hour ? Couple of hundreds ? If so, I don't think the **really small** difference between PHP and MySQL will be significant at all.

The question should be more like "where do I put the fact that password are stored using md5" than "what makes me win almost nothing".

And, as a sidenote, another question could be : where can you afford to spend resources for that kind of calculations ? If you have 10 PHP servers and one DB server already under heavy load, you get your answer ;-)

But, just for fun :

```
mysql> select benchmark(1000000, md5('test'));
+---------------------------------+
| benchmark(1000000, md5('test')) |
+---------------------------------+
|                               0 |
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (2.24 sec)
```

And in PHP :

```
$before = microtime(true);
for ($i=0 ; $i<1000000 ; $i++) {
    $a = md5('test');
}
$after = microtime(true);
echo ($after-$before) . "\n";
```

gives :

```
$ php ~/developpement/tests/temp/temp.php
3.3341760635376
```

But you probably won't be calculating a million md5 like this, will you ?

*(And this has nothing to do with preventing SQL injections : just escape/quote your data ! always ! or use prepared statements)*

Comment: When all else fails, conduct an experiment.

Comment: so you'll save approximately one microsecond doing it in the database as opposed to doing it in php.  sounds pretty negligible, but interesting to know nonetheless

Comment: +1 for a very thorough answer and important point about SQL injections :)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know which is faster, but if you do it in PHP you avoid the possibility of SQL injection.

Comment: In any case I make  mysql_real_escape_string on my $pwd params .

Comment: This has nothing to do with it. A prepared statement would fix this without moving the MD5 function, also you're relying on the PHP MD5 function to "escape" the password.

Comment: @Draemon: i didn't say there weren't other ways around it, but the example doesn't give any indication of escaping the parameter.  @hiam: if you decide to do it in php, you shouldn't escape the password string first. php's md5 function can take any string, and it's guaranteed to return ^[0-9a-f]{32}$

Answer (score 3):

Is performance really an issue here? It's likely to be marginal.

- Doing it in MySQL makes the DB do more work, which is a good thing
- Doing it in MySQL means the cleartext password gets passed further along (and the DB connection is often unencrypted).
- This has nothing to do with SQL injection. You could fix the first version without moving the MD5 function. Also if there was a bug in PHP's MD5 function there's still a possibility of an injection attack.

Comment: What bug in md5 function? Are you expecting to somehow exploit it and instead of 32 hexadecimal digits output some special characters and well formed sql statement? Not gonna happen.

Comment: That's exactly the sort of attitude that leads to exploits. You shouldn't use arbitrary functions and hope they sanitise your data. What if someone removes the MD5 requirement at some point - are they going to realise the data isn't safe?

Comment: This is just silly, you can't then trust even any escaping function, or to bring it to extreme any function at all. Even php itself or mysql can be buggy. So only way to avoid exploits is to not write any code.

Comment: I said *arbitrary* function. An escaping function is not arbitrary. If you change/remove a call to such a function you should know you might be exposing a flaw. It would not be obvious to me that removing/changing a call to md5() could introduce an injection issue. The correct way to handle this is to make sure all user input is sanitized by functions *specifically designed* to avoid vulnerabilities, and that applies equally to both cases - thus injection vulnerability is not an issue pertinent to the OP.

Comment: How is having the DB do more work a good thing? Getting another web server to handle more load is easy. Getting another DB server makes things complicated.

Comment: @Echo: You're right, I didn't really mean "do more work" in a computational sense, more that you're encapsulating the storage format in the DB, which in this case is a good thing. I really didn't make that very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Measure it, it's the only way to be certain.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, read the column value out of mysql, then compare the result with the computed hash in your client code (e.g. php).

The main reason for doing this is that it avoids stupid things such as the database collating the column in a non-binary fashion (e.g. case-insensitive etc), which is generally undesirable for a hash.