# MD5 and SHA hash functions in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, performance, locking, optimistic

I've implemented the optimistic in mysql database using MD5 and SHA-1 and everything work well. 
My problem is that i don't know if this is the best solution as i don't know how much time mysql take to calculate each hash.
Here is the method

```
select field1 , field2 ,sha1(field1),md5(field2) from mytable
where id = someValueHere

update mytable set column1=value1,column2=value2
where id= someValueHere  
and sha1(field1) = storedValue
```

this method gives you the possibily to not touch your databse or make changes on it. But as i've mentionned i need to know more details about performance of this method.

Comment: This might answer your question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184543/whats-faster-better-to-use-mysql-md5-function-or-run-md5-php-function)

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what is the purpose of those hashes? In the second query is unclear where `storedValue` comes from, and assuming `id` is a primary key - why do you need to compare hashes?